# Proving $G$ is 4-colorable given subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I've been stumped on the following problem:

> Assume that the 4-colors theorem is proven for all planar graphs with
>   less than $n$ vertices and that $G$ is a graph with $n$ vertices that
>   contains the following subgraph:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i47Uk.jpg]

> And suppose that we let the induction hypothesis give us a coloring of
>   the six outer vertices a,b,c,d,e,f. This gives us the following
>   configuration:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXIO7.jpg]

> **Conclude from this that G is 4-colorable.**

I'm not sure how to proceed here. There are so many ways that this subgraph can exist as part of a larger graph $G$ that I'm not sure how to prove 4-colorability can be maintained. Of course the subset of $G$ that does not contain the above subgraph is 4-colorable (by assumption), but then?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are we to suppose that this particular coloration was obtained from the induction, or is that just a sample coloration, and it needs proved for all possible colorations of the outer vertice? If the former, the solution is easy: just come up with a coloration of the black vertices that works (there are two such colorings).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Assume this particular coloration was obtained from induction on just the outer vertices. But how does the coloration on the black vertices prove the broader graph $G$ is necessarily 4-colourable? What guarantees that the union of the two graphs doesn't break colorability? We already know by assumption the subgraph is 4-colorable.

Comment: The way I interpret the wording is that one removes the 4 center vertices and their associated edges *from the entire graph*, not just the subgraph, and applies the induction hypothesis. The resultant graph is now 4-colored, and the 6 outside vertices happened to be colored as shown. So all that remains is to color the 4 center vertices. That is why it is easy. If this is just a sample coloration, then you need to figure out colorations of the center for every possible coloration of the outside vertices, which is a lot more cases - through reducible by symmetries.

Comment: Paul Sinclair's interpretation must be correct.  If the top red node is instead colored blue, and the bottom red node colored yellow, then the coloring cannot be extended to a proper $4$-coloring. The black nodes on the left and right are adjacent to blue, green, and yellow, so must be colored red.  Then the black nodes one the top and bottom are adjacent to red, blue and yellow, so they must both be colored green, and they are adjacent.